# replace sections of top lines using regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I want to use regular expression to replace portions of every first line of sections of text in a file:

Example:

```
SSM_289|19wer12.stf_ALSO010100002_1 # 2567 # 2451 # 1 # OK=3_9;tremid=22;stretu_myce=DSA;tfs_ertsg=TDFFAR/TTGGAT;fsr_ssuat=23-16hg;te_donh=2.117
some texts...............
some texts...............
some texts...............
```

Expected output:

```
SSM_289| [19wer12.stf_ALSO010100002_1]
some texts...............
some texts...............
some texts...............
```

my attempt did not work:

```
perl -pi -e "s/^(\SSM_\d*\|)(\w*\.stf_[a-z][A-Z][0-9]*_\d*)\s\#\S*/$1 [$2]/g" file.txt
```

Suggestions to get the code working will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your pattern failed because of `stf_[a-z]`

Comment: since the question was edited after hjpotter's answer, with the regex still with `stf_[a-z]`: please do consider his advice. He is right: the first letter after stf_ is a capital letter, not matched by [a-z].

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I still couldn't get it to work after changing  as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or use this pattern

```
\|([^# ]+).*
```

and replace with `|[$1]`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hF5bY4/2)

```
\|              # "|"
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^# ]         # Character not in [^# ]
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
.               # Any character except line break
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
```

Comment: Thanks alpha bravo. For some reason, I got this: SSM_289| []. The $1 did not print.

Comment: which language are you using, try `\1` instead of `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first `|` and `#` will always be where you want to cut off

```
/(.*\|)(.*?)\s#.*$/$1 [$2]/
```

Since you didnt specify a language, I'm leaving it in generic form.

[Example link](http://regex101.com/r/yI6tC4/1)